# App works incorrect at prod server on Heroku, but all is good at localhost

Tags: node.js, heroku, cloudflare

So, i`ve got both backend(node/express/mongodb) and frontend(vue/ionic) on heroku, at different dynos. Also, I use Cloudflare to change domain CNAME (app.herzen-schedule.ru (frontend), backend.herzen-schedule.ru(backend)), to give more in depth explanation.

I`ve got one function that scrapes a page from a different website(cheerio) and then sends the data from the website via endpoint at backend. At this point it works perfectly at localhost, but when I deploy the app to Heroku, this endpoint returns nothing at all, just an empty array that was initialized in case to store data from scraped page.

Scrape function

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const date = new Date()

    let dateFrom = req.body.dateFrom
    let dateTo = req.body.dateTo
    let groupID = req.body.groupID

    if (!dateFrom) dateFrom = date.toLocaleDateString()
    if (!dateTo) dateTo = new Date(date.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 190 * 1000).toLocaleDateString()

    await axios.get(`https://guide.herzen.spb.ru/static/schedule_dates.php?id_group=${groupID}&date1=${dateFrom}&date2=${dateTo}`)
        .then(r => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(r.data)
            const table = $('table.schedule > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr')

            const schedule = []
            let scheduleItem = null

            table.each((i, el) => {
                if ($(el).attr('class') === undefined) {
                    if (scheduleItem) {
                        schedule.push(scheduleItem)
                        scheduleItem = {
                            date: $(el).find('th.dayname').text(),
                            subjects: []
                        }
                    } else {
                        scheduleItem = {
                            date: $(el).find('th.dayname').text(),
                            subjects: []
                        }
                    }
                } else if ($(el).attr('class') === 'lowline' || $(el).attr('class') === 'lowline oddrow') {
                    let subject = {
                        time: $(el).find('th').text(),
                        name: $(el).find('td[colspan=2] > strong').text(),
                        moodleHref: $(el).find('td > strong > a').attr('href'),
                        lecturer: $(el).find('td > a').text(),
                        lecturerHref: $(el).find('td > a').attr('href'),
                        type: $(el).find('td').contents()['1'].data,
                        date: $(el).find('td').contents()['3'].data.replace('(', '').replace(')', ''),
                        place: $(el).find('td').contents()['5'].data.substr(2)
                    }
                    scheduleItem.subjects.push(subject)
                }
            })

            Promise.all(schedule)
                .then(async schedule => {
                    console.log(schedule)
                    await res.send(schedule)
                })
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
})
```

Actually, it should return something like this:

```
[
  { date: '5.04.2021, понедельник', subjects: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { date: '6.04.2021, вторник', subjects: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  {
    date: '7.04.2021, среда',
    subjects: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    date: '8.04.2021, четверг',
    subjects: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    date: '9.04.2021, пятница',
    subjects: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  { date: '10.04.2021, суббота', subjects: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { date: '12.04.2021, понедельник', subjects: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
]
```

I`ve thought cheerio could not keep up scraping another website and response is sent before the page is scraped, but it seems to be a bit strange since I tried to refactor the function with promises and lots of different things.

I do not know what could help to get the point, but I suppose logs from Heroku can shed the light.

```
2021-04-05T02:42:27.641705+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/auth/user/" host=backend.herzen-schedule.ru request_id=8200f2a7-002e-491d-9df3-c43d23bbb18a fwd="178.70.97.55,172.68.245.180" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=204 bytes=360 protocol=http
2021-04-05T02:42:27.891022+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/user/" host=backend.herzen-schedule.ru request_id=d2942641-469a-451b-a22d-00fb4ceacc89 fwd="178.70.97.55,172.68.245.180" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=100ms status=304 bytes=823 protocol=http
2021-04-05T02:42:28.406772+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/schedule/" host=backend.herzen-schedule.ru request_id=6b7486c0-a543-42ef-92d8-99a0fc9bd6df fwd="178.70.97.55,172.68.245.180" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=204 bytes=360 protocol=http
2021-04-05T02:42:29.302205+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/schedule/" host=backend.herzen-schedule.ru request_id=caaac922-ac77-45f4-b1a6-6361893c7b5c fwd="178.70.97.55,172.68.245.180" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=616ms status=200 bytes=879 protocol=http
2021-04-05T02:42:29.302744+00:00 app[web.1]: []
```

I could provide more info about anything, just tell where to search.

Answer (score 0):

As always, toLocaleDateString() broke the logic as to parse the page I need 'ru' locale, but the Heroku server is in USA and returns locale date :)